# Android bottom menu

Tags: android, menu

I’ve created a bottom menu and used a relative layout to place it there but I don’t know if I’m going about this the right way. It’s a PNG bar with three images on it one for maps, one for facilities and one for search which all should lead to a three different activities.

How do I make each image a button, I know how to make the whole bar a button, in a webpage you can add an image map and create hotspost with the three links.

How do I do that in an Android application?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make each image a button

You use three images, and use each in an `ImageButton`.

Even better would be to follow platform conventions, either:

- Using an ordinary options menu, which will automatically be hoisted to your action bar on Android 3.0+, and where you can make some of those be toolbar buttons if you want for immediate clickablilty
- Using an action bar library for all Android versions, such as [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), so you have the same behavior everywhere, including the toolbar buttons where there is room

Comment: Thanks bud! I kind of thought it had to be three images but wasnt sure if there was a better way or not. I used three images in a gridview and it works great. I’m building for 2.2+ as I need to accommodate for the lowest common denominator but not too far back and I only want the menu on one screen. Cheers, Mike.

Comment: Sorry, me again. I was going about this all wrong and what I needed was a tabview, cheers, Mike.